# Linear transformations for fixing the line $y = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

The professor says that the subgroup for "stabilizing" the line $y = 0$ is

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
  a & c \\ 
  0 & d
 \end{bmatrix}$$

because in order to fix the first basis vector, $b = 0$. The first column represents the transformation on the first basis vector, and the second column represents the transformation on the second basis vector. So to fix the line, the first basis vector is taken into some multiple of the first basis vector. So the coefficient of the second basis vector in the matrix will be $0$.

I did not understand any of this. Shouldn't $b$ and $d$ both be $0$ if you don't want to fix $y$? And doesn't this linear transformation $A$ he gave take a vector $(x ,y) \to (ax+cy, dy)$? I don't see how this fixes or "stabilizes" the line $y=0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your last sentence is completely correct. Now take a point on the line $y = 0$, say, $(x, 0)$. According to you, this transforms to $(ax + c \cdot 0, d \cdot 0) = (ax, 0)$, which is another point *on that same line*. So the line (as a set, not as individual points!) remains fixed.

Does that help?

If you want to have each point of the line $y = 0$ remain fixed, you need a matrix of the form 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & c\\
0 & d
\end{bmatrix},
$$
which may have been what you thought the prof was saying.

Comment: Wow, yes, I completely misunderstood. You explained it very well, thank you!